# Wyeast yeast replacements: US-05?

Tags: yeast, stout, imperial, wyeast

it's my first question here.

I've downloaded [Brewdog recipe book](https://www.brewdog.com/diydog), and they use yeasts like `Wyeast 1056 - American Ale`, `Wyeast 1272 - American Ale II` and `WLP099 Super High Gravity Ale` for **Imperial Stouts**.
Recipes: #6, #7, #21, #29, #70.

In my country I can't buy these yeasts, but I can buy `Fermentis Safale` and `Mangrove Jacks`.

I found out that `Safale US-05` is a replacement for `Wyeast 1056 - American Ale`. Is it correct?

What is the replacement for `Wyeast 1272 - American Ale II`? And for `WLP099 Super High Gravity Ale` (I need it for `Tokyo*`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, kind of....WY1056, WLP001 and US-05 all had the same original source, but through time and the process of drying 05, they've diverged a bit.  1056 and 001 are very clean, with the main differences being mouthfeel.  US-05 is not as clean and has a tendency to throw a peach/apricot ester that I and others find disagreeable.  But it's pretty much as close as you're going to get in a dry yeast.  There is no dry replacement for 1272.  And US-05 will work as a replacement for 099 if you pitch more of it to account for higher gravity.

Comment: Thanks! So, what yeast would you recommend for Imperial Stouts?

Comment: Given your options, I'd go with 2-3 packs of US-05.  What's the OG of the imperial stout?

Comment: 1.157 (36% plato)

Comment: Wow....3-4 packs of US-05.  Make sure you produce a very fermentable wort.

Comment: I used two packs of US-05 on an extract stout OG 1.076 just a few months ago, because I wanted good attenuation (but honestly I also didn't really know any better at the time) and it actually came out very good....7.3%ABV. Didn't get any esters, but I suppose if it was there the stout could've masked it.

Comment: Do I really need 2+ packs of yeast? I thought that yeast amount is doubled every 24h, so additional yeast won't help.

Comment: Not necessarily the case.  You want to limit reproduction to 3, maybe 4, generations for best results.  Underpitching causes them to have to reproduce more, which weakens the yeast and reduces beer quality  Yeast is as important as every other ingredient you put in your beer.  You wouldn't brew if you had only half the malt or hops, would you?

Comment: @thekolnok, while adequate healthy yeast is important, attenutation depends much more on the fermentablity of the wort than the amount of yeast pitched.

Answer (score 1):

You say you "need it for Tokyo"? If you're patient [Advanced Brewing](http://advanced-brewing.com/0_liquid_yeast.html) ships specialty yeasts in Japan, though they don't update their stocks so you'll need to check with them to see what they have available by trying to place an order first.

I've also been impatient myself and used alternate strains as replacements. In my research I've found that many strains just go by different names from different manufacturers. There are others that can be found with a simple Google search but [here is one chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19rL_C_d2BCp-QJ43zeFtl7D0i3cryMa_Uz81EkvS5ow/edit?authkey=CP-m-dUJ&hl=en&authkey=CP-m-dUJ&hl=en&authkey=CP-m-dUJ#gid=3) to help with your conversions. Scroll to cell 202 to read about US-05.

As for your specific question about yeast for stouts, I recently used S-04 for my own "Darjeeling Oatmeal Stout" recipe--and it worked wonders, making a delicious brew--so I'd say go for it!

Comment: `Tokio*` is a name of this Stout, I'm from Russia :)
https://www.brewdog.com/item/3/BrewDog/Tokyo.html
Thank you for the table.